# You must call removeView () with the AddView in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-linearlayout

I create a table dynamically thus described below
and works well ....

http://s24.postimg.org/wgofs717p/ex_Tables.png

```
mLinearLayout.removeAllViews()
MyTableLayout mTableLayout = new MyTableLayout(...);
for (int j = 0; j < numberOfTables; j++) {
    for i =0; i<numberOfLines; i++{
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
        R.layout.line_layout,((ViewGroup) MyTableLayout.getChildAt(i)), false);
        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.numeroRespostaDialogId)).setText("text");
        (ViewGroup) tableLayout.getChildAt(i)).addView(v);
        }
    mLinearLayout.addView(mTableLayout);
}
```

Now I need to put it to be created in a AsyncTask
And I basically did the same way it did without the AsyncTask

```
protected ArrayList<MyTableLayout> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        mArray<MyTableLayout>
        MyTableLayout mTableLayout = new MyTableLayout(...);
        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfTables; j++) {
            for i =0; i<numberOfLines; i++{
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.line_layout,((ViewGroup) MyTableLayout.getChildAt(i)), false);
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.numeroRespostaDialogId)).setText("text");
                (ViewGroup) tableLayout.getChildAt(i)).addView(v);
        }
        mArray.addView(mTableLayout);
    }
    return mArray;  
    }

    onPostExecute(){
        mLinearLayout.removeAllViews()
        for i=0  to mArray.size ++{
            mLinearLayout.addView(mArray[i]);
            }
        }
```

Using this AsyncTask I get the error

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView () on the child's parent first.

and put the removeAllViews () into the "For" of OnPostExecute ... works however only shows the last column;
 
  How can I do to add view in LinearLayout with AsyncTask iterating a array of Views...

I can not understand why out of AsyncTask works and when I put in AsyncTask get the error

Thanks for the help...

------------------Edit------
This Work... =/ but why didnt work with the "For"

```
onPostExecute(){
  //for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++) {
    mLinearLayout.addView(myArray.get(0));
    mLinearLayout.addView(myArray.get(1));
    mLinearLayout.addView(myArray.get(3));
  //}
 }
```

//
----------EDIT2 --------------------

I do not know why .. but is WORKING without any alteration =D

Comment: IMO you shouldn't change view structure (adding/removing views) depending on data. It's slow, not efficient, not elegant and error-prone. Consider using adapter. You can use existing adapter or create your own adapter and use pattern like in ListViewAdapter or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this...

```
if(itemView.getParent() != null){
   ((ViewGroup)itemView.getParent()).removeView(itemView);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply
but now its working, im using the same source that is asked. i dont know what was wrong before